# Porque o console não retorna nada?

Tags: javascript, funções, checkbox, google-chrome-extensão

Olá, estou criando uma **extensão pro Chrome** para ativar algumas funções através de checkbox. Como exemplo para teste, coloquei que se o resultado fosse true, teria que mostrar `checked` no `console.log`, o mesmo para se fosse false (`unchecked`). Por algum motivo o código não funciona.

Segue o código abaixo.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){

document.getElementById('onoff').addEventListener('click', function(){
        function verificarCheckBox1() {
    var check = document.getElementById('onoff');
        for (var i=0;i<check.length;i++){ 
            if (check[i].checked == true){ 
                console.log('Checked')
            }  else {
      console.log('UnChecked')
            }
        }
        }
    
    function verificarCheckBox2() {
    var check = document.getElementById('onoff2');
        for (var i=0;i<check.length;i++){ 
            if (check[i].checked == true){ 
                console.log('Checked')
            }  else {
      console.log('UnChecked')
            }
        }
        }    
    
    })
    }
    )
```

```css
body {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #422256;
}

.toggle {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.toggle > input {
    display: none;
}

.toggle > label {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    width: 44px;
    background: #898989;
    border-radius: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.toggle > label:after {
    position: absolute;
    left: -2px;
    top: -3px;
    display: block;
    width: 26px;
    height: 26px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    content: '';
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.toggle > label:active:after {
    transform: scale(1.15, 0.85);
}
.toggle > input:checked ~ label {
    background: #6fbeb5;
}
.toggle > input:checked ~ label:after {
    left: 20px;
    background: #179588;
}
.toggle > input:disabled ~ label {
    background: #d5d5d5;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.toggle > input:disabled ~ label:after {
    background: #bcbdbc;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Auto Refresh - Linx</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
    <div class="toggle">
    <input id="onoff" type="checkbox">
  <label for="onoff"></label>
    </div>
  
  <div class="toggle">
    <input id="onoff2" type="checkbox">
  <label for="onoff2"></label>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem alguns pontos que precisam ser vistos:

- Você está atribuindo o evento click apenas no primeiro checkbox:

```
document.getElementById('onoff').addEventListener('click', function(){
```

- Você utiliza do método `getElementById`, que retorna apenas um elemento, mas faz um `for` no mesmo, isso normalmente é feito quando utilizamos métodos como `getElementsByClassName`, que retorna vários elementos:

```
var check = document.getElementById('onoff');
for (var i=0;i<check.length;i++){
```

- Por fim, o seu evento apenas declara duas funções e não faz a chamada delas:

```
function verificarCheckBox1() {
function verificarCheckBox2() {
```

---

Isso tudo pode ser feito de diversas maneiras diferentes, abaixo um exemplo, onde crio a função `checked` que somente faz a verificação do `checkbox`:

```
function checked(checkbox) {
  if (checkbox.target.checked){ 
    console.log('Checked');
  } else {
    console.log('UnChecked');
  }
}
```

*Obs.: Eu recebo como parâmetro o evento, logo para acessar o elemento, eu usa a propriedade `target` e por fim, verifico a propriedade `checked`, como ela é um boolean, eu não preciso comprarar com `true`.*

Agora eu posso simplesmente adicionar o evento click e utilizar essa função para ambos os checkbox:

```
document.getElementById('onoff').addEventListener('click', checked);
document.getElementById('onoff2').addEventListener('click', checked);
```

---

Veja o abaixo o exemplo completo:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  function checked(checkbox) {
    if (checkbox.target.checked){ 
      console.log('Checked');
    } else {
      console.log('UnChecked');
    }
  }

  document.getElementById('onoff').addEventListener('click', checked);
  document.getElementById('onoff2').addEventListener('click', checked);
});
```

```css
body {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #422256;
}

.toggle {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.toggle > input {
    display: none;
}

.toggle > label {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    width: 44px;
    background: #898989;
    border-radius: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.toggle > label:after {
    position: absolute;
    left: -2px;
    top: -3px;
    display: block;
    width: 26px;
    height: 26px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    content: '';
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.toggle > label:active:after {
    transform: scale(1.15, 0.85);
}
.toggle > input:checked ~ label {
    background: #6fbeb5;
}
.toggle > input:checked ~ label:after {
    left: 20px;
    background: #179588;
}
.toggle > input:disabled ~ label {
    background: #d5d5d5;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.toggle > input:disabled ~ label:after {
    background: #bcbdbc;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Auto Refresh - Linx</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class="toggle">
  <input id="onoff" type="checkbox">
  <label for="onoff"></label>
  </div>
  
  <div class="toggle">
    <input id="onoff2" type="checkbox">
    <label for="onoff2"></label>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Incrível! A forma como você explicou cada parte separada e depois mostrou na prática como funciona é demais! Muito obrigado mesmo.